# ng2 + webpack refer html dom element in external library

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

Hello Angular 2 and Webpack developers,
I have been working with angular 2 and systemjs since quite a while, new to webpack (starting to love it with a bit of struggle).

I have a component that has html as follows:

```
  <div id="partners-slider" class="partners">
        <div class="partners__slider js-slick-slider">
          <a class="partners__item"><img src="assets/logo-company-1.png" alt="">Elite Construction Group, LLC</a>
          <a class="partners__item"><img src="assets/logo-company-2.png" alt="">Pro Era Limited</a>
         </div></div>
```

Its basically a slider.
I have a library that I use in a lot of projects, for animations and stuffs.

Theres a function as follows that initiates a slider:

```
function initPartnersSlider(container) {
var $partnersSlider = $(container) ;
if (!$partnersSlider.length) return;

$partnersSlider
  .find('.js-slick-slider')
  .slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    autoplay: true,
    accessibility: false,
    prevArrow: $partnersSlider.find('.js-partners-prev'),
    nextArrow: $partnersSlider.find('.js-partners-next'),
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1100,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 4
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1000,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });}
```

function call:

```
initPartnersSlider('#partners-slider');
```

Problem here is    `$partnersSlider.length` is always 0.

As per my understanding, the html element is placed inside a minified file by webpack (prod)

> main.bundle.js

I am referring my external javascript file inside index.html as a script tag. It doesnt seem to recognise the dom element with `id="properties-slider"` as the element is inside main.bundle.js?. I am able to debug and see it in my library code.

Has anyone done that before?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A probable solution to this problem is having a settimeout before calling methods. If there are better solutions please post.

```
setTimeout(() => {
     initPartnersSlider('#partners-slider');
    }, 0);
```

Not very convincing, but worked for me.